# Lookup and Append

Tags: awk

Guys can you help me with the awk script, 
I've been thinking of using NR=FNR method and substring but doesn't work

here is my input

file 1.txt

```
bscrnc|cellname|cellid
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004A
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004B
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004C
BBIR1|BIR005G+LINGONG|BI3005A
BBIR1|BIR005G+LINGONG|BI3005B
```

file2.txt

```
MB2|MBO
BP5|BPD
JH1|JHO
TN5|TTN
TK3|TKNJ
KT5|KTN
LG4|LGS
BI3|**BIR**
BH0|BIH
```

the output

```
bscrnc|cellname|cellid|sitename
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004A|BIR004
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004B|BIR004
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004C|BIR004
BBIR1|BIR005G+LINGONG|BI3005A|BIR005
BBIR1|BIR005G+LINGONG|BI3005B|BIR005
```

we look at the third field that the first 3 words are BI3 in the 1st file, then we see in the 2nd file BI3->BIR
and then we append it in the fourth field
and the last three letter/words is taken from the next three words from the 1st file

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were on the right track (though, as often pointed out here, more people might have helped sooner if you had given more details about what you tried and where you thought the problem was).

#### bl.awk

```
BEGIN { FS = "|"; OFS = FS }

# Build the mapping from the first file (file2.txt)

NR == FNR {
    sitemap[$1] = $2;
    next;
}

# Print the header and rows from the second file (file1.txt)

FNR == 1 { $4 = "sitename"; print; }

FNR > 1 {
    sitekey = substr($3, 1, 3);
    sitevalue = sitemap[sitekey];
    sitesuffix = substr($3, 4, 3);
    print $1, $2, $3, sitevalue sitesuffix;
}
```

Note that we want to put file2.txt first on the command line so we can build the map before printing the rows from file1.txt:

```
bash-3.2$ awk -f bl.awk file2.txt file1.txt
bscrnc|cellname|cellid|sitename
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004A|BIR004
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004B|BIR004
BBIR1|BIR004G+AW_GEUT|BI3004C|BIR004
BBIR1|BIR005G+LINGONG|BI3005A|BIR005
BBIR1|BIR005G+LINGONG|BI3005B|BIR005
```

Comment: Thank you very much! very detailed, easy to understand! and btw how to distinguish between the code for the first and the second file?

Comment: You're welcome! and yes, good question. You already know that the `NR == FNR` (overall record number equals record number within the file) will only be true for the first file. The `next;` statement in that block says "immediately go to the next record and don't look at any more code". Hence the only way a record can get past that block is if `NR != FNR`, which of course means it's the second (or in general, any but the first) file.